# Compiled library crashes at WolframLibraryData_new

Tags: code-generation, ccompilerdriver, c-codegenerator

I am using `CreateLibrary` to create a dynamic library of a Mathematica function, so that it can be linked into standalone code, but I run into segmentation faults (after repeated calls) in WolframLibraryData.

The Mathematica function looks something like:

```
func = {E1 S1, E7 (-(S2/10) - 6 S7) + E8 (-(S2/10) - 6 S7) + 
  E2 ((6 S2)/5 + 12 S7), 4 E3 S3 - 2 E4 S3, -2 E3 S3 + 4 E4 S3, 
 4 E5 S4 - 2 E6 S4, -2 E5 S4 + 4 E6 S4, 
 E2 (-(S2/10) - 6 S7) + E8 (-(S2/30) + 2 S7) + E7 ((2 S2)/15 + 4 S7), 
 E2 (-(S2/10) - 6 S7) + E7 (-(S2/30) + 2 S7) + E8 ((2 S2)/15 + 4 S7)};

sigcomp = Compile[{{s, _Real, 1}, {e, _Real, 1}},
  Block[{S1, S2, S3, S4, S7, E1, E2, E3, E4, E5, E6, E7, E8},
   S1 = s[[1]];
   S2 = s[[2]];
   S3 = s[[3]];
   S4 = s[[4]];
   S7 = s[[6]];
   E1 = e[[1]];
   E2 = e[[2]];
   E3 = e[[3]];
   E4 = e[[4]];
   E5 = e[[5]];
   E6 = e[[6]];
   E7 = e[[7]];
   E8 = e[[8]];
   func
   ],
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]
```

Then, with `Export` I create a .c-file. Another .c-file serves as the wrapper for this function and is based on the lowpassmainSrc code on https://reference.wolfram.com/language/CCodeGenerator/tutorial/Examples.html#333777088:

```
#include "sigcomp.h"
#include "WolframRTL.h"
#include "stdio.h"

int leafsig(double *s, double *e, double *csig)
{
    WolframLibraryData libData = 0;

    int err = 0;

    WolframLibraryData libData = WolframLibraryData_new(WolframLibraryVersion);

    Initialize_sigcomp(libData);

    MTensor s_in;
    MTensor e_in;
    MTensor sig_out;

    mint nconst = 6;
    mint nsig = 8;
    mint i;

    err = libData->MTensor_new( MType_Real, 1, &nconst, &s_in);
    if(err) return 1;
    err = libData->MTensor_new( MType_Real, 1, &nsig, &e_in);
    if(err) return 1;
    err = libData->MTensor_new( MType_Real, 1, &nsig, &sig_out);
    if(err) return 1;

    // put input into MMA tensors
    for (i = 1; i <= nconst; i++){
        libData->MTensor_setReal(s_in,&i,s[i-1]);   
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= nsig; i++){
        libData->MTensor_setReal(e_in,&i,e[i-1]);   
    }

    // run MMA function
    err = sigcomp(libData, s_in, e_in, &sig_out);
    if(err) return err;

    for (i = 1; i <= nsig; i++){
        libData->MTensor_getReal(sig_out,&i,&csig[i-1]);
    }

    libData->MTensor_free(s_in);
    libData->MTensor_free(e_in);
    libData->MTensor_free(sig_out);

    WolframLibraryData_free(libData);
    Uninitialize_sigcomp(libData);

    return 0;

}
```

These two files and the WolframRTL_Static_Minimal library are compiled into a library (.dylib, macOS 10.13) with `CreateLibrary`. This works without errors. The library can be included in my standalone code and produces expected results. After repeated calls, though, there is a segmentation fault, which according to valgrind seems to originate from the line

```
WolframLibraryData libData = WolframLibraryData_new(WolframLibraryVersion);
```

Valgrind says

```
==98098== 1 errors in context 1 of 132:
==98098== Invalid read of size 8
==98098==    at 0x1001F9E6C: RandomState_fromSpecification (randomgenerator.cpp:451)
==98098==    by 0x1001FA5AD: init_rtl_randomgenerator(int) (randomgenerator.cpp:739)
==98098==    by 0x1001F897C: InitRandom(int) (init_random.cpp:21)
==98098==    by 0x100187AB3: InitializeRuntimeLibrary (initialize.cpp:28)
==98098==    by 0x100182038: WolframLibraryData_new (WolframRTL.cpp:37)
==98098==    by 0x1000BA82F: leafsig (in /Users/mn/Documents/research/num-model/c/libleafsig.dylib)
==98098==    by 0x100000E7F: main (main.c:15)
==98098==  Address 0x54485254 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==98098== 
==98098== 
==98098== 1 errors in context 2 of 132:
==98098== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==98098==    at 0x102AA0A0B: pthread_getspecific (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==98098==    by 0x1001FA5AD: init_rtl_randomgenerator(int) (randomgenerator.cpp:739)
==98098==    by 0x1001F897C: InitRandom(int) (init_random.cpp:21)
==98098==    by 0x100187AB3: InitializeRuntimeLibrary (initialize.cpp:28)
==98098==    by 0x100182038: WolframLibraryData_new (WolframRTL.cpp:37)
==98098==    by 0x1000BA82F: leafsig (in /Users/mn/Documents/research/num-model/c/libleafsig.dylib)
==98098==    by 0x100000E7F: main (main.c:15)
==98098==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==98098==    at 0x1000AC086: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.14.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==98098==    by 0x1001F880C: New_KThreadLocalStorage (os-thread.cpp:352)
==98098==    by 0x1001F932A: RandomGeneratorMethod_add (randomgenerator.cpp:220)
==98098==    by 0x1001F8983: InitRandom(int) (init_random.cpp:22)
==98098==    by 0x100187A4F: InitializeRuntimeLibrary (initialize.cpp:28)
==98098==    by 0x100182038: WolframLibraryData_new (WolframRTL.cpp:37)
==98098==    by 0x1000BA82F: leafsig (in /Users/mn/Documents/research/num-model/c/libleafsig.dylib)
==98098==    by 0x100000E7F: main (main.c:15)
```

Am I doing something wrong or is there a problem with the Wolfram runtime library?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the line

```
WolframLibraryData_free(libData);
```

in my wrapper c-file causes this problem. Removing it solves the segmentation fault happening after repeated calls. The line shouldn't have been there in the first place; it's not there in the Wolfram.com CCodeGenerator tutorial I linked to, either.